# PHP stops after faile PDO query

Tags: php

I am running the below code and know that this is the suspect peice as I have placed an echo above and below it. The first runs fine but the second does not.

If I change the query to something like "show tables" it will run but I cannot see what if anything is wrong with this. I have checked reserved words and syntax. Am I missing something obvious!

```
try
{ 
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) AS val FROM users WHERE username=:user');
    $sth->binvalue('user',$_POST['user']);
    $sth->execute();    

}
catch(PDOException $e)
{  
    echo $e->getMessage();  
}
```

Comment: @RobertRozas WHere? I don'T see that one..

Comment: It's supossed to be try{the code}catch{}

Comment: `binvalue` is wrong - anyway, this should have logged a relevant error/warning/notice somewhere.

Comment: @RobertRozas that's what it is :)

Comment: @RobertRozas ANd it is.

Comment: @RobertRozas does the edit help you?

Comment: ooooops there it is...i just missed it, my fu...ng keyboard xD

Answer (score 6):

There is a type error:

instead of

```
$sth->binvalue('user',$_POST['user']);
```

Try

```
$sth->bindvalue('user',$_POST['user']);
         ^
```

Comment: It should be added that this would've been super simple to figure out by A: Enabling errors or B: Looking in your logs. Most likely "*Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO_Statement::binvalue()*"

Answer (score 3):

```
$sth->binvalue('user',$_POST['user']);
```

should be

```
$sth->bindValue(':user',$_POST['user']);
```

Notice both the `bindValue` and the `:user`